# How do I properly configure the SonarQube MSBuild Scanner from the solution's perspective?

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

I am configuring the MSBuild scanner to run against a C# solution.  I am also running code coverage via dotCover, but that it is working.  Fundamentally, the problems are - 1. the generic test execution report parser thinks the paths are incorrect and 2. SonarQube is parsing the test execution reports repeatedly (which is less important to me).

- First, I'm running all of my commands from within a Jenkins Groovy Pipeline script.
- Next, I'm trying to not have to enumerate projects in the solution.  By using the targets files described in [1], I'm able to run dotnet test from my solution folder.
- I'm generating TRX output from the VSTest adapter and converting that to the Generic Test Data format [4] due to the bug described in [2].  I'm converting it with an XSLT I wrote (but largely based off of a TRX to JUnit XSLT I found), see [3] if you're curious.

  1. https://gist.github.com/dasMulli/6fb5d1f507b886aeebaf27069f47f895
  2. https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/886
  3. https://gist.github.com/awesley/3118ba06282a7190400666c6c4e25e8d
  4. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data

My solution structure is something like

```
    (CWD from Jenkins' perspective) Source/
    Source/my.Sln
    Source/Proj1/Proj1.csproj
    Source/Proj1.Tests/Proj1.Tests.csproj
```

This allows me to run a sequence of commands that looks something like:

```
    SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /d:sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=convertedXmlCommaDelimitedList
    dotnet test Source/my.Sln -l trx
    grep for trx files -> use xslt to generate convertedXml in the same dir, coupled to how convertedXmlCommaDelimitedList is generated
    SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

The specific error I see is "Test execution data ignored for 2 unknown files, including:".  It occurs regardless if the paths are absolute or not.  It is here that I see each project's "convertedXml" file parsed regardless if that file belongs to the project that is being post-processed.

I have tried a few things I found online, such as renaming my "Source" directory to something else.  I worry that I'm going to need to write a script that takes a particular csproj at a time to parse, and have to maintain the list of csproj's in my solution.  Ideally, that can be avoided.

Comment: You've tagged this with 'c'. Did you mean c#, as in the title?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Sure did.  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse trx data to Generic Test Data to feed SonarCloud you can use this dotnet tool: https://github.com/gmarokov/dotnet-trx2sonar

Just remember to use `sonar.testExecutionReportPaths` when passing the report path.